# How to keep "/" in string while using sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed

```
packageUrl="http://192.168.0.112"
packageUrl_line=`grep -n "packageUrl" ${file} | head -1 | cut -d ":" -f 1;`
sed -ig "${packageUrl_line},${packageUrl_line}s/\"packageUrl\".*/\"packageUrl\":\"${packageUrl}\",/g" ${file}
```

As code, it throws an error, because packageUrl contain "/", how to resolve this problem without modify packageUrl?

> sed: 1: "2,2s/"packageUrl":.*/"p ...": bad flag in substitute command: '/'

Comment: That use of `grep` to find the first matching line is suspect for two reasons - first, `fgrep` or equivalent is more likely what you want, and secondly, you should be able to make `sed` replace only the first matching line (e.g. in GNU sed, with a `0,/.../` address range).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use `/` as your sed `s` delimiter.  It's happy with most characters:

```
sed 's,bob,tony,'
```

for example.

Comment: You can use control characters like `^A` (control-A) too; they're not part of a legitimate URL, whereas a comma could appear in a URL.  But the basic point of "you don't have to use slash" is quite correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try to escape the literal `/`:

```
packageUrl="http:\/\/192.168.0.112"
```

Comment: Any other way? I dont want to modify packageUrl

Comment: Yes, changing the sed delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Your shell may support substitution in parameter expansion.  It looks a bit cryptic with `\` and `/`, but in Bash:

```
$ echo "$packageUrl ${packageUrl//\//\\/}"
http://192.168.0.112 http:\/\/192.168.0.112
```

The leaning toothpicks `//\//\\/` breaks up as follows:

> `//` replace all
>   `\/` occurrences of the single character `/`
>   `/` with
>   `\\/` the two characters `\` and `/`

If you use a different delimiter for sed's `s` command, you get a more readable substitution.  For example, using `@` as delimiter, you can write `${packageUrl//@/\\@}`.

If you can pick a delimiter that you are *absolutely sure* won't be present in `$packageUrl`, then you can skip the substitution entirely - but be sure that you're sure!